# Android Quiz Game - Countdown timer for each qstion

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown

I have created a Quiz app for Android using the tutorial here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/getting-started-complete-android-app.html

For each question, the user will only have 20 seconds to answer it. If he/she fails to answer in 20 seconds, an `AlertDialog` will popup and the game will terminate.

To do this, I have added a counter in the `OnCreate` method of `QuestionActivity class`:

```
final TextView myCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
    new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timeUp();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myCounter.setText("Time left: "
                    + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }

    }.start();


public void timeUp() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            QuestionActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Times up!")
            .setMessage("Game over")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            QuestionActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

The counter works displays and functions on screen correctly. After answering a question, the activity moves to the next question and the counter resets itself to 20 seconds again.

**The problem**

The quiz has 15 questions, after answering 3 or 4 questions, the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
07-18 00:49:05.530: E/AndroidRuntime(4867): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41533a80 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I believe this relates to the `AlertDialog`. I have looked up this error code on Stackoverflow and the popular solution is to pass `ActivityName.this` as the context when building the `AlertDialog`.

Unfortunately this does not solve the problem.

I believe the counter is setting a time limit of 20 seconds for the whole activity. My requirement is 20 seconds for each question.

However, the counter resets to 20 seconds when the user press the' `Next` button and the activity moves to the next question.

Should I be resetting the counter when the user presses the `Next` button? Here is the `OnClickListener` code for the `Next` button

```
if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
                    SHOULD I ADD SOMETHING HERE?
        finish();
```

**Can anyone help me code a solution to my problem?**

Here is all the code in `QuestionActivity.class`

```
public class QuestionActivity extends SherlockActivity implements
    OnClickListener {

private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    /**
     * Configure current game and get question
     */
    currentGame = ((ChuckApplication) getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();

    Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button quitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quitBtn);
    quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    //Update the question and answer options..
    setQuestions();

    final TextView myCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
    new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // myCounter.setText("Time up!");
            timeUp(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myCounter.setText("Time left: "
                    + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
    }.start();
}

public void timeUp(Context context) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            QuestionActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Times up!")
            .setMessage("Game over")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            QuestionActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

/**
 * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current
 * games current question
 */
private void setQuestions() {
    // set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    // set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

    TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //validate a checkbox has been selected
    if (!checkAnswer())
        return;

    //check if end of game
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it has then check if its
 * correct and update gamescore
 */
private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    if (answer == null) {
        // Log.d("Questions", "No Checkbox selection made - returning");
        return false;
    } else {
        // Log.d("Questions",
        // "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            // Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
        } else {
            // Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    RadioButton c4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    if (c1.isChecked()) {
        return c1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c2.isChecked()) {
        return c2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c3.isChecked()) {
        return c3.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c4.isChecked()) {
        return c4.getText().toString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the activity doesn't exist anymore at a certain point when you try to make the dialog(probably when the `CountDownTimer` is near the end?!?).

Anyway I think finishing and starting the same activity for each question isn't such a good idea, instead you could use the current activity and simply restart the timer. For example:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends SherlockActivity implements
    OnClickListener {

   private CountDownTimer mCountDown;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // ...
      mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // myCounter.setText("Time up!");
            timeUp(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myCounter.setText("Time left: "
                    + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
      }.start();
      // ...
```

and in the `onClick` callback do the same to setup a new question, stop the old timer and restart the new timer:

```
//check if end of game
if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
} else {
    if (mCountDown != null) { 
       mCountDown.cancel();
    }  
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
    setQuestions();
    mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // myCounter.setText("Time up!");
            timeUp(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myCounter.setText("Time left: "
                    + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
    }.start();  
}
```

Also, in the callback for the `Dialog`'s `Button` I would first close the `Dialog` before finishing the `Activity`:

```
((AlertDialog) dialog).dismiss();
QuestionActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I will give this a try when I get home tonight.

Comment: I've added all your code and the counter problem has been fixed. However, when the quiz is over and I start EndgameActivity.class, after 20 seconds I get a WindowManager$BadTokenException error. It looks like the timer is still running and trying to display the AlertDialog. I am using finish() after starting the EndgameActivity activity. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @tiptopjat Add the same code to stop the timer for the case when the game is over: `if (currentGame.isGameOver()) { if (mCountDown != null) { 
       mCountDown.cancel();
    }  ...` and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks. I have only have one issue now. In my original solution, the radio buttons for each question would all be unchecked when moving to a new question. After implementing your solution, the radio button selected from the previous question is still selected in the next question...

Comment: Fixed it by adding `radioGroup.clearCheck()` at the start of `setQuestions()` method.