# Android Quiz App countdown

Tags: android, android-studio, countdown

my code is given below in that for Each Question there is i.e. when count down ends its jump to next question and count down starts again, i want that when the countdown ends it should jump to the result page..and even after jumping to next question countdown should not stop.

```
 @Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    questionPlay = db.getRuleQuestionMode(mode);
    totalQuestion = questionPlay.size();

    mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(TIMEOUT, INTERVAL) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
            progressValue++;

        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCountDown.cancel();

        }
    };
    showQuestion(index);
    db.close();
}


private void showQuestion(final int index) {

    if (index < totalQuestion) {
        thisQuestion++;
        txtQuestion.setText(String.format("%d/%d", thisQuestion, totalQuestion));
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressValue = 0;


        txtView1.setText(questionPlay.get(index).getQus());
        btnA.setText(questionPlay.get(index).getAnswerA());
        btnB.setText(questionPlay.get(index).getAnswerB());
        btnC.setText(questionPlay.get(index).getAnswerC());
        btnD.setText(questionPlay.get(index).getAnswerD());
        mCountDown.start();

        Button btnca =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnca);
        btnca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StyleableToast st= new StyleableToast(getApplicationContext(),questionPlay.get(index).getCorrectAnswer(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                st.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                st.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                st.setCornerRadius(3);
                st.show();
                score-=10;
            }
        });

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Done.class);
        Bundle dataSend = new Bundle();
        dataSend.putInt("SCORE", score);
        dataSend.putInt("TOTAL", totalQuestion);
        dataSend.putInt("CORRECT", correctAnswer);
        intent.putExtras(dataSend);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    mCountDown.cancel();
    if (index < totalQuestion) {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        if (clickedButton.getText().equals(questionPlay.get(index).getCorrectAnswer())) {
            score += 10; // increase score
            correctAnswer++; //increase correct answer
            showQuestion(++index);



        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(50);
            showQuestion(++index); // If choose right , just go to next question
        }
        txtScore.setText(String.format("%d", score));
        //clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if(mCountDown != null)
        mCountDown.cancel();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you are lookng for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532684/android-quiz-game-countdown-timer-for-each-qstion?rq=1

Comment: Yes it helped me but the thing is countdown is working in the same way as i was expecting but not the progress bar

Comment: So you want that if progress bar has a value of 5 at the end of one question, when the next question starts progress bar will have 5 again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `mCountDown.start();` in your `showQuestion` method.

in your `onFinish` method, call your results page from there

Comment: what should i do with progress bar so that it should be continue when i go to next question

Comment: I see you calling `progressBar.setProgress(0);` in your `showQuestion` method, any reason why you setting progress to 0 when ever you showing next question??

Comment: Well thank you sir, i knew i am making silly mistake

Comment: Glad to help. As a newcomer of the community - when you receive an answer to your question, you should mark it as solved